# Mathematica GPU occupancy is too high when the current page has high quality images

Tags: image-processing, gpu

When Mathematica's current page contains a high-quality picture, the GPU occupancy rate will increase and the current page delay of Mathematica will increase( the software is slow to respond to my operation.). When I slide the mouse wheel down and turn to the page which does not contain high-quality pictures, and there is no delay of the software, the GPU utilization rate is reduced.

If my current page contains a high-quality graphic like the following code, the GPU utilization rate will become very high:

```
Eo[x_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] = If[15 >= x >= -15 && x <= -z, 1, 0];
DensityPlot[Eo[x, z], {z, -100., 100.}, {x, -100., 100.}, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 Frame -> True, PlotPoints -> 200, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

This problem just appeared today and I have never met this problem before. I want to know if I accidentally set an option wrong? Is there any way to solve this problem?
When Mathematica is used to display high-quality graphics, is it normal to increase the utilization rate of GPU to 70% ?
I try to resetting my Mathematica like this:[How do I fix common problems by resetting Mathematica to its default configuration?](https://support.wolfram.com/12464), but it didn't work.
By the way, when I reopen a Mathematica project file, the original `In[]`and `Out[]` numbers are all gone, it told me `In[3] is a previous session`, like this:
[image]
This my GPU utilization rate screenshots, mathematica doesn't do anything except show me a picture that I've already computed.
[image]

Comment: The first thing that springs to mind is that you could `Rasterize` to turn it into just a dumb image, if that's something you can get away with.

Comment: What do you mean by current page delay?

Comment: @Patrick Stevens I don't quite understand what you mean. So when Mathematica is used to display high-quality graphics, it's normal to increase the utilization rate of GPU? So we can use `Rasterize` to reduce the use of GPU? But I don't think the picture above is very complicated. How can it make my GPU occupancy rate reach 70%?(My GPU is 1650s)

Comment: @ MarcoB It just like the game delay, the software is slow to respond to my operation.  When I turn to the next page, the current page does not contain high-quality pictures, and there is no delay of the software.

Comment: @shrocat From the screenshot, I assume you are on Windows. I cannot reproduce this behavior with your code on MMA 12.0 on Win10-64bit. The GPU utilization remains at zero and I get no lag in the MMA window. Just to state the obvious, have you already restarted your whole system etc.? What is your setup exactly (e.g. output of `$Version`)?

Comment: @MarcoB  That's the problem, i don't know what I did. I just opened my Mathematica as usual, but it suddenly became stuck.  Then I tried to run other Mathematica files, and it happened again when it came to complex images. After looking for it, I found that the GPU occupancy was too high. Maybe I accidentally pressed a shortcut key for setting something up? But now I don't know which setting is the problem. And my version is `12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 14, 2020)`

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot that kind of thing. I’d try contacting Wolfram support with this (https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=technical). They are probably better equipped to deal with this kind of problem than this community is, unless one of us has had a similar problem in the past.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for doing this. I think I've found where the problem is , it might be Nvidia drivers' incompatibility. My driver was automatically updated to version 461.09 yesterday and I reduced it to version 456.71 which published on 2020/10/07, and  GPU occupancy reduced to about 15%. My CPU is Core i7-9700 and My GPU is GTX1650s, and my version is 12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit). Maybe this is really needed to be solved with Wolfram support, but a reduced version of the driver is a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit:***
I upgraded the version to 12.2 and the program was fixed.
After talking to the Wolfram technicians, they suggested me to upgrade the version to 12.2 , which proved to be effective.

***The original answer：***
I think I've found the solution, it might be Nvidia drivers' incompatibility. My driver was automatically updated to version 461.09 yesterday and I reduced it to version 456.71 which published on 2020/10/07, and GPU occupancy reduced to about 15%. My CPU is Core i7-9700 , my GPU is GTX1650s, and my version is 12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit).

Despite the reduced GPU occupancy, Mathematica still suffers some delay (like game action delay ) when displaying high-quality images on the current page. Compared to the 15% GPU occupancy of the page showing high-quality images, the page there are no high-quality images which has GPU occupancy about 1%, and CPU occupancy becomes less too. I don't think the images I'm showing should have such a delay, at least for GTX1650s there shouldn't be a delay for such an image I think. Does anyone else have a significant delay in Mathematica when displaying high quality images?

But this is only a temporary solution after all, and I'm not sure if the driver conflict is specific to my computer only or if it's a general phenomenon.
If this is a general phenomenon, it need to be required an official solution by the developer.

Comment: I’m glad you found a (temporary) solution. It might still be beneficial if you let Wolfram know, particularly since, if it’s really a widespread problem with nVidia drivers, only WRI could fix it.

Comment: @MarcoB  It's a really annoying question, and I will try to let Wolfram know.